# What is the difference between these two template syntaxes inside gruntfiles?

Tags: underscore.js, gruntjs

```
<config:path.src>
```

versus

```
<%= path.src %>
```

In some examples I've seen, the first is used in the "long" way of defining src/dest in targets, and the second example is used on the "short" way. But this isn't consistent so it seems that they are used interchangeably in gruntfiles. Any enlightenment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form `<config:path.src>` was called a **directive** in Grunt prior to 0.4. They allowed to perform different task depending on the directive associated (`config:`, `json:`, `file_temaplte:`).

In Grunt 0.4, these have been deleted to be used through by more standard format:

- `<config:prop.subprop>` → `<%= prop.subprop %>`
- `<json:file.json>` → `grunt.file.readJSON('file.json')`
- `<file_template:file.js>` → `grunt.template.process(grunt.file.read('file.js'))`

So as you can see, in the case of the `config:` directive, this was truly equivalent to `<%= %>` underscore template tags.

But directive where also allowing other action.

More about this here (in *Configuration* section): https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I read the grunt docs a lot, I must have missed this somehow.